# Zend2: Creating a radio button list with extra information?

Tags: zend-framework2

So far I have this:

```
$radio = new Element\Radio('gender');
$radio->setLabel('What is your gender ?');
$radio->setValueOptions(array(
        array(
                '0' => 'Female',
                '1' => 'Male',
        )
));
```

The problem is, I want a table output like this:

```
Gender   | Description       | Button
-------------------------------
Male     | The workers       | [X]
Female   | The peacekeepers  | [ ]
```

So the problem is that I want to associate more information to the individual form elements and alter the standard way the get printed to the screen. If something like this could work, I would be pretty happy:

```
$radio = new Element\Radio('gender');
$radio->setLabel('What is your gender ?');
$radio->setValueOptions(array(
        array(
                '0' => 'Female',
                '1' => 'Male',
        )
));
$radio->setExtraData(array(
        array(
                '0' => 'The workers',
                '1' => 'The peacekeepers',
        )
));
```

That obviously doesn't work. So what is the correct "zend" way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of providing a plain array, you could add extra information in the value options like this:

```
$radio->setValueOptions(array(
    array(
        'value' => '0',
        'label' => 'Female',
        'description' => 'The peacekeepers',
    ),
    array(
        'value' => '1',
        'label' => 'Male',
        'description' => 'The workers',
    )
));
```

The following step would be to create a custom [View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html) for rendering the table, or loop through the options and render the table in the view itself.